# Calcute days beetween last day of a list and today

Tags: python, list, dataframe, datetime

I have some problem in understanding how to get as result a number of days that I can check if it is greater of a number like `5/10/12/15` etc...

```
import datetime 
import pandas as pd
list_dates=[]
file_list = ["2021-05-05","2021-05-07"]
for fname in file_list:
      list_dates.append(fname)
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=["Data"])
for row in list_dates:
   date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(row, '%Y-%m-%d')
   df.loc[row] = date_time_obj  
last = df.iloc[-1]                 
miss = (datetime.datetime.now() - last)
print(miss)
```

This code get me a result like a time delta:

```py
Data   34 days 00:03:58.032944
Name: 2021-05-07, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

In the original code I don't have `file_list` directly with those data but I get those data from code above this part

Comment: You can access the number of days using `Series.dt.days`, try printing `miss.dt.days.values`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the number of days as a rounded down int, you can do
`miss.Data.days` which returns `34`. However, if you want to compare the time difference to a number of days (`34 days 00:03:58.032944` is greater than 34 days when you take into account minutes), you can do the following

```
from pandas import Timedelta
miss.Data > Timedelta(days=34)
```

returns

```
True
```

Answer (score 1):

`miss` itself is a pandas Series containing one element, which is of type `timedelta64[ns]`.

To extract a number of days from a `timedelta64[ns]` object, you can simply run `my_timedelta.days` - in your case, `miss[0].days`.

To apply such an operation to every element of the pandas Series, you can use `miss.dt.days`.